# Java Android XML Parsing with DOM

Tags: java, android, xml

In my android application (Minimum SDK version 4) have to communicate with a server to get some data and receive them as a XML response stream. Following is a sample response

```
<Orders>
  <Orders>
    <OrderID>1000</OrderID>
    <OrderDate>20/04/2015 11:35:50</OrderDate>
    <Reference>ttt</Reference>
    <Amount>12.50</Amount>
    <Status>0</Status>
    <CustomerName>John</CustomerName>
    <Address>30, George Street, Middlesex</Address>
  </Orders>
  <Orders>
    <OrderID>1001</OrderID>
    <OrderDate>20/04/2015 10:54:35</OrderDate>
    <Reference>ABC</Reference>
    <Amount>40.50</Amount>
    <Status>Pending</Status>
    <CustomerName>Peter Smith</CustomerName>
    <Address></Address>
  </Orders>
</Orders>
```

I need to Parse using Java XML DOM Parser but finding it difficult to read the text content. Getting a waring message saying

> "Call requires API level 8 (current min is 4):
>   org.w3c.dom.Node#getTextContent"

When use following line of code

```
element.getElementsByTagName("Status").item(0).getTextContent();
```

Therefore I tried following way and working alright.

```
element.getElementsByTagName("Status").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue().trim()
```

But I need to check if `[element.getElementsByTagName("Status").item(0) != null]`

That's alright But when it's empty for example `<Status></Status>` need to check 
if `[element.getElementsByTagName("Status").item(0).getFirstChild() != null]` as well...

I am sure there must be a proper way to do this. But didn't find any sample code explaining this. If anyone know the best way to do this (using DOM parser for minimum support SDK 4) would like to hear. Thanks

Comment: Wow...Current min is 4. You are really taking care of all the users!

Comment: Yes, All other functionality works fine for those versions.

Answer (score 0):

try the code below

```
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;
public void checkXML()
{
    try
    {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        String str="<o> <Orders>"+
               "<OrderID>1000</OrderID>"+
               "<OrderDate>20/04/2015 11:35:50</OrderDate>"+
               "<Reference>ttt</Reference>"+
               "<Amount>12.50</Amount>"+
               "<Status>0</Status>"+
               "<CustomerName>John</CustomerName>"+
               "<Address>30, George Street, Middlesex</Address>"+
               "</Orders></o>";
        xpp.setInput( new StringReader(str));
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
        {
            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                System.out.println("Start document");
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
        System.out.println("End document");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need to use a DOM parser? For most xml, I find XStream or similar parsers a lot easier to use.